# He dared to [Go at/go to] the blast site

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I don't remember having read a sentence using *go at + place* until today but today I came across this sentence

> He dared to **go at** the blast site so as to see his colleagues.

Is it all right to use **go at** here or it is better to use **go to**? To my ears **go to** sounds better.

Comment: What is the source? You could change the word order to "He dared to go see his colleagues **at** the blast site." Either that, there is some implied information after *go*, or it is just wrong.

Comment: Sounds wrong to me.....

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing really wrong with *at X* here, but when used with *go* it adds a flavor of "surveying" or investigating/checking up on - in the sense that you are going there and not really having a plan or specific directed activity after you arrive.

In your example:

> He dared to go at the blast site so as to see his colleagues.

the activity is very much directed - you are not really just going to the blast site to wander around, but specifically to see colleagues.  So the "pointed-ness" of *to* is more appropriate than the "area-ness" of *at*.